# how to develope Neo4j database web UI

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I want to develop one web application by using [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) database, where i want to show UI like http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/04/neo4j-rest-server-part1-get-it-going.html,

[image]

any one knows how to proceed on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why its got down voted? i have seen http://processing.org/ is used for this kind of requirement but i am not sure. Please suggest me.

Comment: This UI is done with https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse, an Eclipse RCP application using ZEST for the visualisation.

Comment: Hi @PeterNeubauer thanks for the answer, i need to integrate this UI in web application. can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options, for visualizing in javascript, see for instance Max De Marzi's blog:

http://maxdemarzi.com

Our Neo4j Console is also built using d3.js as visualization and current added jquery datatables, see the [github repository](http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole) and the [test-version](http://console-test.neo4j.org). It can also run against embedded databases and remote servers (see the readme).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i want some thing like http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/01/11/graph-visualization-and-neo4j/ but all these are based on JSON input, is there anything which can connect to Neo4j and shows the graph in UI.

Comment: It's all straight CoffeScript and JSON, look at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/server for the webadmin code.